# How can I find the standard error of the coefficients from an S-estimator?

Tags: r, regression, estimation, estimators

I am using a simple model with a response and predictor variable but I am unable to find a package/function that provides the standard error of the coefficients for the S-estimator.

So, how do I calculate the standard error of the coefficients when using the S-estimator (R code would be nice)? Is there an R package that supports this feature?

My search:

After the function search failed me I researched a bit on S-estimation and came across http://dx.doi.org/10.12732/ijpam.v91i3.7 (free download). On page 354 it goes over S-estimation beifly.

I have looked into the source code for lqs() in r from package MASS, but it did not help much: https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~leslie/MOUSE/r/R-1.8.1/src/library/lqs/R/lqs.R.

Then there is https://wis.kuleuven.be/stat/robust/papers/1998/campbelllopuhaarousseeuw-calculationsestimatorscat.pdf which talks about the S-estimator in depth, but I still cannot find the method for calculating the standard errors of the estimates from the S-estimator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm 2 from http://dx.doi.org/10.12732/ijpam.v91i3.7 seems easy to code:

```
pu<- function(u,ck){
  ifelse(abs(u)<=ck,u^2/2-u^4/(2*ck^2)+u^6/(6*ck^4),ck^2/6)
}

mlqs<-function(x,y,ks=0.6745,K=0.199,cc=1.547,tol=0.0005) { 
  m1<-lm(y~x)
  pout=which(abs(scale(resid(m1)))>3)
  cat(pout, resid(m1)[pout], "outliers?\n") #outliers
  b0=coef(m1)
  ei=resid(m1)
  n=length(ei)
  j=1
  si2=100;si=1
  while(abs(si2/si - 1)>tol){ # IWLS
    cat(j," ")
    if (j==1) si = median(abs(ei-median(ei)))/ks else 
      si = sqrt((1/(n*K))*sum(wi*ei^2))
    ui=ei/si
    if (j==1){wi = ifelse(abs(ui)<=cc,(1-(ui/cc)^2)^2,0)} else
      {wi = pu(ui,cc)/ui^2}
    modw = lm(y~x, weights=wi, method="qr")
    ei = modw$residuals 
    si2 = sqrt((1/(n*K))*sum(wi*ei^2))
    cat(coef(modw), si2,"\n")
    j = j + 1
  }
  list(model=modw,scale=si2,wi=wi)
}  

N=200
set.seed(1240)
x=matrix(rnorm(2*N,2,1.5),ncol=2)
y=34+5*x[,1]+10*x[,2]+rnorm(N,0,2)
y[c(25,50,100)]=y[c(25,50,100)]*5
summary(lm(y~x))
mdsr=mlqs(x,y)
summary(mdsr$model)

> summary(lm(y~x))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-25.69  -8.44  -3.51   1.63 344.49 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   30.087      5.900   5.100 7.96e-07 ***
x1             9.823      1.688   5.820 2.36e-08 ***
x2             9.233      1.826   5.056 9.76e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 35.37 on 197 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2211,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2132 
F-statistic: 27.96 on 2 and 197 DF,  p-value: 2.039e-11

> mdsr=mlqs(x,y)
25 50 100 344.4925 255.0675 221.0073 outliers?
1  33.42785 5.852733 9.784128 2.858832 
2  33.85629 5.338672 9.846785 2.432034 
3  34.04779 5.168414 9.851512 2.303382 
4  34.14641 5.090459 9.851292 2.24485 
5  34.19784 5.051547 9.850973 2.214479 
6  34.22476 5.031453 9.850879 2.197815 
7  34.23894 5.020896 9.850882 2.188422 
8  34.24649 5.015295 9.850902 2.183055 
9  34.25053 5.012305 9.850916 2.179969 
10  34.25271 5.010705 9.850921 2.178187 
11  34.25389 5.009845 9.850922 2.177158

> summary(mdsr$model)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, weights = wi, method = "qr")

Weighted Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.37661 -0.94304  0.07241  0.90805  1.37652 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 34.25389    0.26521  129.16   <2e-16 ***
x1           5.00985    0.08037   62.34   <2e-16 ***
x2           9.85092    0.07969  123.62   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9786 on 197 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9894,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9893 
F-statistic:  9170 on 2 and 197 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```